# How can I make this into one button?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm trying to make it so if the entry field == the password (123), the button to proceed (enterbutton)'s state becomes active rather than disabled. I've only been able to somewhat accomplish this using 2 buttons, though if "123" is entered, and then removed the state of "enterbutton" does not change. How could I make this function all in the "enterbutton" rather than having to have 2 buttons, as well as making it update if said password is removed?

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")


e = Entry(root)
e.insert(0, "Enter your password")

def check():
    password = e.get()
    if password == "123":
         enterbutton["state"] = ACTIVE
    if password != "123":
        enterbutton["state"] = DISABLED

button = Button(root, text="b", width=10, height=3, command=check)
enterbutton = Button(root, text="Enter", state=DISABLED, width=10, height=3,)

e.pack(pady=30)
enterbutton.pack()
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want actually?  Did you want the `Enter` button to enable/disable itself intead of using `b` button?

Comment: Yes, I want the Enter button to be disabled/enabled according to if "123" is in the enter field. @acw1668

Comment: Do you mean that the `Enter` button will be enabled/disabled based on the content of the `Entry` widget _**without clicking any button**_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a StringVar for the entry field. Using its `trace` method, you can set a function that is called every time the text is changed. Also, I strongly recommend importing tkinter as `tk` instead of importing everyting with the * import.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

var = tk.StringVar()
var.set("Enter your password")
e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)

def check(*args):
    password = var.get()
    if password == '123':
        button['state'] = 'normal'
    else:
        button['state'] = 'disabled'
        
var.trace('w', check)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", state='disabled', width=10, height=3,)

e.pack(pady=30)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```